# Cannot access Disk Drives in single-boot Ubuntu Sysytem

Tags: partitioning, mount

I uninstalled my windows through OS-Uninstaller in Ubuntu. But now i am unable to access any of the disk partitions. I am getting following error:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda7 at /media/devil/Programming: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda7" "/media/devil/Programming"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda7': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

What to do? I guess I have to install windows again.. right?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue where I had 2 HDD's, 1TB (windows) and 1TB (server 2012).I was wondering about the same thing.

Basically,This happens because Windows 8, also Including Windows Server 2012 have **"fast boot option"** enabled by default which leads the hard disk not to *shut-down* Completely.

*Since some motherboards have an option to disable it during the boot. If not all you have/had to do was*

- Boot up the windows and launch control panel.
- Look for Power Options and under Advanced power option there is
  **grayed out** checkbox says `fast boot`. You can make this option available by clicking on "Change settings that are currently
  available"
- uncheck the `fast boot` option.
- Now shutdown the computer and boot into Ubuntu.

Do

> `sudo fdisk -l | grep NTFS`

You should be able to mount the desired partitions, Now for example

```
sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb3 Desktop/ntfs
```

Good Luck.